# Android LatLng class in Grails application?

Tags: android, grails

I want to store some geolocation information in web application database. Currently, it is stored as String and published to my app as json.

However, I want to migrate the web part of my application from Ruby on Rails to Grails. Reasons behind that include the possibility of sharing the classes between two app parts.

Is it a good idea to do:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
```

in my grails code?
If not, why and which alternative should I use to store data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will want to use a standard Java/Groovy data-type to persist latitude and longitude as two separate columns in your database as opposed to this Android specific data-type. I would recommend either double or float for these two columns depending on your level of precision (BigDecimal is not required).

Something like this:

```
class Location {
  Double latitude
  Double longitude
}
```